# Car refuses to start with repeated clicking but can be jumped

Tags: battery, alternator, starter, battery-cable, clicking

**Day 1**: My 2013 Infiniti JX35 won't start. When I press the ignition button, the car loses all electrical power and I can hear repeated clicks under the hood.

I installed a **new battery**, and it started up right away and drove fine.

**Day 2**: The problem came back. Here's what I've done:

- Checked the voltage on the battery: 12.6
- Turned on accessories without starting the car: no problems
- Scanned for codes: no codes

Then I jump-started the car:

- Jump-start worked
- Checked the voltage on the (running car) battery: 14.2
- Disconnected the black terminal on the battery: car continued to run

When I turned the car off and removed the jumper cables, it wouldn't start again.

**Day 3**:

I went out to the car to check on things, and it was still clicking from the night before.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Car Battery Dying Overnight - Disconnected](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/8834/car-battery-dying-overnight-disconnected)

Comment: @SolarMike close, but not quite -- I replaced the battery with a new one and the problem persists.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! It sounds like there is a bad connection at your battery. How well did you clean your battery clamps at the terminals when you put the new battery in? Have you checked to see that they are secured tightly?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 that's what I'm leaning toward, too. I'm looking at replacing some of them, but they're pretty elaborate on the JX35. I'll post a follow-up if I'm successful.

Comment: Before you replace them, just ensure everything is clean and there's a good connection. Also ensure there's no bulging in the cable, which would indicate corrosion within the cable itself (this would mean replacement). If you can get away with cleaning, why replace?

Comment: Sounds like a bad starter . Have you had it tested?

Comment: "Disconnected the black terminal on the battery: car continued to run" - avoid doing this.

Answer (score 2):

This ended up being a bad negative terminal connected to the battery. The vibration at engine start was just enough to disrupt the connection. When I jumped the car, the clamp secured the terminal and the connection -- and, of course, the extra juice helped too.

I confirmed at the dealership (don't judge) that the alternator and starter are fine.

Make sure your battery terminals are tight and clean.